# Error when overriding a method in a child class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, typescript-generics

I have this code

```js
class RoomOne {}

class ClassOne { 
  public open<R extends { new(...arg: any): RoomOne }>(RoomConstructor: R = RoomOne): InstanceType<R>{ 
    //////// 
  }
}
```

```js
class RoomTwo extends RoomOne {}

class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {
  public open() {
    return super.open(RoomTwo)
  }
}
```

In ClassTwo, this error appears in the open method

```
TS2416: Property 'open' in type 'ClassTwo' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'ClassOne'.   
Type '() => RoomTwo' is not assignable to type '<R extends new (...arg: any) => RoomOne>(RoomConstructor: R) => InstanceType<R>'.     
Type 'ClassTwo' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<R>'.
```

Here is an example of how to use the open method as expected

```
const instanceClassOne = new ClassOne()
const instanceRoomOne = instanceClassOne.open()
const instanceRoomOne = instanceClassOne.open(RoomOne)
const instanceRoomTwo = instanceClassOne.open(RoomTwo)

const instanceClassTwo = new ClassTwo()
const instanceRoomTwo = instanceClassTwo.open()
```

Do not pay attention to duplication of constants, this is just an example of using the code

How to get rid of this error, it was expected that the inheritance would occur without errors since RoomTwo inherits from RoomOne

Managed to solve the error with

```
class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {
   public open<R extends RoomOne>(RoomConstructor: Constructor<R> = RoomTwo as unknown as Constructor<R>): R {
    return super.open(RoomConstructor)
  }
}
```

Comment: A generic method's type argument is specified by the *caller*, not the *implementer*.  Presumably you should change to something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOL7RN) where `ClassOne` is itself generic and not `ClassOne.open`.  Does that meet your needs? If so then I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The idea is that the open method in ClassOne can be used both directly in code and in inherited classes such as ClassTwo.In ClassOne.open, arguments can be both RoomOne and classes inherited from it, such as RoomTwo. The generic type is introduced to output the return value.The problem with your solution is that when creating ClassOne and using open with the RoomTwo argument, the return value will be RoomOne, unless of course when creating the object we did not specify generic R as RoomTwo, but then we will have the return type RoomTwo and it will no longer be possible to use with RoomOne.

Comment: There should be flexibility here, I hope my problem has a solution.

Comment: Please demonstrate your above text description of the problem with code. ([edit] the code in the question to show the required use case my solution fails to meet)  I’m afraid I don’t understand it and my IDE definitely doesn’t understand it.